# UNIX -grep 2nd character

Tags: command-line, text-processing

So here's a sample line in my script:

```
echo "Enter time(MILITARY FORMAT)(i.e 1245): "
read time`
```

so for example the user's input is `1315`
how do i grep the 3rd and 4th digit (15) and then the output should be like this

```
Your time is 13 hours and 15 minutes
```

Comment: Grep is line matching tool, not appropriate for this task. Use Parameter expansion bas heemayl shows in his answer

Answer (score 2):

You should do this using just `bash`, using `bash` parameter expansion:

```
$ time=1315

$ hr="${time%??}"  ## getting first two characters

$ min="${time#??}"  ## getting last two characters

$ echo "Your time is "$hr" hours and "$min" minutes"
Your time is 13 hours and 15 minutes
```

Or string slicing (Thanks @Serg for mentioning), note that the index starts at 0:

The format is:

```
${parameter:offset:length}


$ time=1315

$ hr="${time:0:2}"  ## getting chars at index 0 and index 1

$ min="${time:2:2}"  ## getting chars at index 2 and 3

$ echo "Your time is "$hr" hours and "$min" minutes"
Your time is 13 hours and 15 minutes
```

If you insist on `grep`:

```
$ time=1315

$ hr="$(grep -o '^..' <<<"$time")"  ## getting first two characters

$ min="$(grep -o '..$' <<<"$time")"  ## getting last two characters

$ echo "Your time is "$hr" hours and "$min" minutes"
Your time is 13 hours and 15 minutes
```

Comment: Heemayl , you're very close. Use ${var, char,1}. Simply gets char position, but offset by 1 is not inclusive

Answer (score 1):

Use `cut`:

```
echo asdf | cut -c 3-4
```

Returns `df`,

More uses:

```
echo asdfghi | cut 3-
```

Returns `dfghi`, works the same the other way (`-5` is everything up to  5 characters).

For your specific case:

```
printf "Enter time(MILITARY FORMAT)(i.e 1245): "
read time
hours="`echo $time | cut -c 1-2`"
minutes="`echo $time | cut -c 3-4`"
echo "Your time is "$hours" hours and "$minutes" minutes"
```

This will work for all valid 4 digit military time inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Using parameter expansion:

```
$ printf "Enter time in military format(HHMM):" && read TIME                                                              
Enter time in military format(HHMM):1512

$ echo your time is "${TIME:0:2}" hours and  "${TIME:2:2}"                                                                    
your time is 15 hours and 12
```

Or you can use python to do the job:

```
$ python -c "time=str(${TIME}); print 'your time is',time[:2], 'hours and ',time[2:],'minutes'"                           
your time is 15 hours and  12 minutes
```

Or AWK:

```
$ awk -v time=${TIME} 'BEGIN{print "Your time is ",substr(time,1,2)," hours and ",substr(time,3),"minutes"}'              
Your time is  15  hours and  12 minutes
```

grep is a line matching tool so it is not the best for this task, but it can match 2 chars at a time, thus here is a method but i do not recommend it:

```
$ array=( $(grep -o -E '.{0,2}' <<< "${TIME}") )                                                                          

$ echo ${array[1]}
12

$ echo Your time is ${array[0]} hours  ${array[1]} minutes                                                                
Your time is 15 hours 12 minutes
```